# Can I use a newer InnoDB plugin in Ubuntu MySQL?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, innodb

The MySQL that comes with Ubuntu 10.04.2 is 5.1.41, which is distributed by MySQL with InnoDB 1.0.5. But for some reason Ubuntu ships it with InnoDB 1.0.

Can I install InnoDB 1.0.5 (or newer?)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to build mysql from source. Instructions for your particular distro are found on google, the mysql site will also have generic linux install info.

Comment: Why? What's the purpose of the plugin architecture if I have to rebuild mysql?